# Using Yii 1 I want to give my main menu a css style but cant figure it out with bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, yii

```
<div id="mainmenu">
    <?php $this->widget('zii.widgets.CMenu', array(
        'items'=>array(
            array('label'=>'Home', 'url'=>array('/site/index')),
            array('label'=>'About', 'url'=>array('/site/page', 'view'=>'about')),
            array('label'=>'Contact', 'url'=>array('/site/contact')),
            array('label'=>'Login', 'url'=>array('/site/login'), 'visible'=>Yii::app()->user->isGuest),
            array('label'=>'Logout ('.Yii::app()->user->name.')', 'url'=>array('/site/logout'), 'visible'=>!Yii::app()->user->isGuest),
            array('label'=>'Users ('.Yii::app()->user->name.')', 'url'=>array('/user'), 'visible'=>!Yii::app()->user->isGuest),
            array('label'=>'Uren ('.Yii::app()->user->name.')', 'url'=>array('/uren'), 'visible'=>!Yii::app()->user->isGuest)
        ),
    )); ?>
</div><!-- mainmenu -->
```

My question is how i cant give the buttons a style by using Twitter Bootstrap.

This is the HTML

```
   <div id="mainmenu">
        <ul id="yw3">
            <li><a href="/urenregistratie/index.php?r=site/index">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="/urenregistratie/index.php?r=site/page&amp;view=about">About</a></li>
            <li><a href="/urenregistratie/index.php?r=site/contact">Contact</a></li>
            <li><a href="/urenregistratie/index.php?r=site/logout">Logout (admin)</a></li>
            <li><a href="/urenregistratie/index.php?r=user">Users (admin)</a></li>
            <li><a href="/urenregistratie/index.php?r=uren">Uren (admin)</a></li>
        </ul>    
    </div><!-- mainmenu -->
```

Please help me out.

Comment: Can you post the generated HTML?

Comment: Yes, Sure @ManojKumar

Comment: How do you want them to look like? What is the CSS you are trying? You will need to override the Twitter bootstrap CSS, not sure if it is getting applied. Please create a demo.

Comment: @ManojKumar Yes i did make a example  for just using css.
I have internship so i'm learning to program.
But they want me to do this with twitter bootstrap so..

Comment: Hmmm. Show us the example you did with just CSS. It will help us find a solution for you.

Comment: @TwanHoltmaat you could try [Yiistrap](http://www.getyiistrap.com/site/index) or [Yii Booster](http://yiibooster.clevertech.biz/) instead. These may be easier to work with.

Comment: @ManojKumar I cant put my css in here..

Comment: @topher Ooh thanks i will check that out !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [itemCssClass](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CMenu#itemCssClass-detail), [activeCssClass](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CMenu#activeCssClass-detail) and [htmlOptions](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CMenu#htmlOptions-detail) to set the classes for the list items, active list item and list(`ul`) respectively. As an example:

```
$this->widget('zii.widgets.CMenu', array(
    'itemCssClass' => 'navbar-item',
    'activeCssClass' => 'navbar-active',
    'htmlOptions' => array('class' => 'navbar'),
    'items'=>array(...)           
));
```

Alternatively, you could try [Yiistrap](http://www.getyiistrap.com/site/index) or [Yii Booster](http://yiibooster.clevertech.biz/) instead. These may be easier to work with.